# Removing white spacing between stacked elements in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to remove spacing between elements stacked on each other.

This is what i have:

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 40%;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 29px;
  border-style: none;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-width: 0;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin-left: -100px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 29px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<form>
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your email"><input type="submit">
</form>
```

I have tried `top:0;` and `bottom:0;` but it does not seem to solve my problem in this example.

Comment: what spaces are you refering to ?

Comment: between input text and button

Comment: reduce the `input[type='text']` width if you are trying to reduce the space between them, or i am not getting what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` on `input[type="text"]`

```
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
    width: 40%;
    height:30px;
      border-radius: 29px;
     border-style:none;
      padding-right:100px;
      padding-left:30px;
      border-width: 0;
}
input[type="submit"] {
 
    
    margin-left: -100px;
   height:30px;

    width: 100px;


    border-width: 0;
     border-radius: 29px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
body {
background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<form>
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"  placeholder="Enter your email"><input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the top bottom padding of input[type="text"].

```
input[type="text"] {
  width: 40%;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 29px;
  border-style: none;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `height` property from both elements and added it to the container, the `form`. Then added `display: flex` to the form.

```css
form {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 29px;
  border-style: none;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-width: 0;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin-left: -100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 29px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<form>
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your email"><input type="submit">
</form>
```